# Dynamic Name Space

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am new to XML transformations (XSLT).
I am trying to figure out a namespace issue I am facing and need some help.

Details below:

### XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Address xmlns="http://gov.co.uk">
            <xsl:variable name="NameSpace">http://gov.co.uk/Test/1</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="Name" namespace="{$NameSpace}">
              <ForeName>Rex</ForeName>
              <MiddleName>XYZ</MiddleName>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="street" namespace="{$NameSpace}">
              <DoorNo>123</DoorNo>
            </xsl:element>
        </Address>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### OutPut XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Address xmlns="http://gov.co.uk">
    <Name xmlns="http://gov.co.uk/Test/1">
        <ForeName xmlns="http://gov.co.uk">Rex</ForeName>
        <MiddleName xmlns="http://gov.co.uk">XYZ</MiddleName>
    </Name>
    <street xmlns="http://gov.co.uk/Test/1">
        <DoorNo xmlns="http://gov.co.uk">123</DoorNo>
    </street>
</Address>
```

As you can see, the namespace for the `ForeName` is xmlns="http://gov.co.uk" which is derived from the root node `Address`, but I need it to be derived from the closest parent node `Name`, i.e. xmlns="http://gov.co.uk/test/1".

I have some thing like this below

```
<xsl:element name="ForeName" namespace="{$NameSpace}">REX</xsl:element>
```

but I am not convinced with this as I have some hundreds of elements in my XSLT file and I need to modify every element like above.

Is there any way we can force the child elements namespace to derive from its parent node ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `<Address>`, `<ForeName>` and `<MiddleName>` have the same namespace is that you add them as literal result elements. **Literal elements acquire copies of the namespace definitions that are in their scope in the stylesheet.** In your example this is done on the line `<Address xmlns="http://gov.co.uk">`. **On the other hand elements produced with xslt commands** (like `<xsl:element>` or `<xsl:copy>`) **do not copy namespaces defined in the stylesheet.**

If you need to put all the literal elements, except `<Address>`, into namespace `http://gov.co.uk/Test/1` just add a default namespace definition `xmlns="http://gov.co.uk/Test/1"` in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element and create `<Address>` element with `<xsl:element name="Address" namespace="http://gov.co.uk">`.

If your literal elements have several different namespaces, then add that namespace definition into the nearest parent of your literal elements. For example use `<xsl:element name="Address" namespace="http://gov.co.uk" xmlns="http://gov.co.uk/Test/1">` to put all literal descendants of `<Address>` to `http://gov.co.uk/Test/1` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is less about XSLT, but more about namespacing in general. When you declare a namespace, that is *active for that node and all subsequent nodes*.

So if you want the default namespace of `ForeName` and `Middlename` to match that of the parent `Name`, you just need to not declare it on the child elements, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Address xmlns="http://gov.co.uk">
    <Name xmlns="http://gov.co.uk/Test/1">
        <ForeName>Rex</ForeName>
        <MiddleName>XYZ</MiddleName>
    </Name>
    <street xmlns="http://gov.co.uk/Test/1">
        <DoorNo>123</DoorNo>
    </street>
</Address>
```

Comment: I think he needs to handle a non-static namespace.

Comment: @CarloCannas I'm not as sure, but without an input XML to go on, its hard to say. The approach OP has taken works for dynamic namespaces using attribute value templates, but it seems the namespace is fixed, OP just wants it to cascade to the child elements, as this shows.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way we can force the child elements namespace to derive from its parent node ?

Not directly, the simplest approach may be to do the transformation in two stages.  First do your current transformation, storing the result in a variable, then re-process the contents of that variable to "move" any no-namespace elements into the specific namespace you have as a parameter:

```
<xsl:param name="NameSpace" select="'http://gov.co.uk/Test/1'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="stageOne">
    <!-- your current processing here -->
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="fix-ns" select="msxsl:node-set($stageOne)" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- copy everything as-is ... -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="fix-ns">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="fix-ns" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ... except element in no namespace, which we move into $NameSpace -->
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = '']" mode="fix-ns">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$NameSpace}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="fix-ns" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If you do actually want no-namespace nodes to inherit their parent's namespace rather than using a fixed namespace for them all then you could change the final template to something more like

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = '']" mode="fix-ns">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="fix-ns" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

---

The third option - you mention that you've already worked out that you can do what you need by using `<xsl:element>` everywhere but that you

> have some hundreds of elements in my XSLT file and I need to modify every element like above.

Remember that an XSLT stylesheet is itself an XML document, so you could use a simple one-off stylesheet like the following to make the necessary edits to your existing stylesheet.  Note the use of [`xsl:namespace-alias`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-namespace-alias) to output XSLT tags:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:out-xsl="urn:result" exclude-result-prefixes="out-xsl">

  <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="out-xsl" result-prefix="xsl" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- match any literal result element <foo> which is not in a namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="xsl:template//*[namespace-uri() = '']">
    <!-- replace it with <xsl:element name="foo" namespace="{$NameSpace}"> -->
    <out-xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{{$NameSpace}}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </out-xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```